# Install ffmpeg (perl package) on windows xp

Tags: perl, ffmpeg, cpan

I'm trying to install [ffmpeg](http://search.cpan.org/~allenday/FFmpeg-6036/FFmpeg.pm) by typing "cpan install FFmpeg" in my command prompt. I've got Image::Magick, Image::PBM, Image::Magick::Iterator installed, which, I understand, are some of the prerequisites that I need, but it appears that that's not enough. [Here's](http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/A/AL/ALLENDAY/FFmpeg-6036.readme) some additional information. I get the error message:

```
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lavcodec
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lavformat
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lz
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -ldl
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lmp3lame
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -logg
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lvorbis
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lvorbisenc
In file included from ffmpeg.h:2,
             from FFmpeg.xs:16:
./ffmpeg-6036.c:21:22: avformat.h: No such file or directory
./ffmpeg-6036.c:22:21: swscale.h: No such file or directory
./ffmpeg-6036.c:23:23: framehook.h: No such file or directory
./ffmpeg-6036.c:24:21: dsputil.h: No such file or directory
./ffmpeg-6036.c:25:17: opt.h: No such file or directory
./ffmpeg-6036.c:44:21: version.h: No such file or directory
./ffmpeg-6036.c:45:22: cmdutils.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm guessing that I need to install those files and tell the installer where to find them. How do I do that, if that's what I need to do?

Comment: You are missing C libraries and C headers. I don't want to sound snarky, but you have chosen an operating system that does not come with a C compiler. You Perl installation comes with a minimal C compiler needed to build modules but linking with external libraries gets harder.

Answer (score 0):

From the [FFmpeg](http://search.cpan.org/~allenday/FFmpeg-6036/) page:

> FFmpeg (in this module, referred to here as FFmpeg-Perl) is a Perl interface to the base project FFmpeg (referred to here as FFmpeg-C).

It looks like the Perl FFmpeg module is just a wrapper around the C library.  If that's the   If you're using MinGW, it might be that you don't have FFMpeg installed in your MinGW environment (the C library.)  You'll need to install that first, and then try installing FFmpeg (the Perl library) again.